# Is there any way to hide back up files (i.e files ending with "~") in Mac OS when using ls command?

Tags: macos

How can I get rid of showing backup files when I use ls command in Mac OS terminal?

I tried `alias ls='ls --hide="*~"'` in `~/.zshrc` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install GNU ls :

```
brew install coreutils
```

then you point your `ls` alias to use GNU ls version.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. I am a new user of Mac so I do not know many trivial things.